# Как осуществить рефакторинг web-проекта

Tags: вёрстка, веб-программирование, рефакторинг, style-guide

Имеется многолетний, большой проект. Средний интернет магазин. За всю историю проекта, дизайн частично и полностью переверстывался не однократно.
Думаю, типичная ситуация многих больших проектов. 
Пришла задача рефакторинга `HTML`, `CSS`, `JS` кода. И создание Style-guide проекта.

Что мы уже сделали:

1. Создали типизацию лэйаутов страниц сайта.
2. Мокапы основных типов страниц.
3. Мокапы header и footer.
4. Мокапы всех страниц и состояний.
5. А так же готов UI-toolkit.
6. Определились с методом верстки.
7. Выбрали препроцессор - `Sass`.
8. Решили какой `HTML`, `СSS` фреймворк будем использовать.

Далее по плану - верстка UI-toolkit, создание снипитов с использованием sass, в наших руках будут большинство элементов сайта. Дальше, пока, конкретного плана нет. Хочется заглянуть вперед, для организации продуктивного решения задачи.

Кто сталкивался с подобной, не простой задачей, исходя от вашего опыта, поделитесь по какому плану вы действовали, что стоит учесть?

Answer (score 2):

Ох, у вас больше похоже на переписывание проекта. Определитесь с тем как будет происходить рефакторинг: постранично (что-то новое, а что-то старое) или стразу все переписывать (т.е. то что не отрефакторено - не работает)

**Если первый вариант**: разбейте проект на составляющие, лучше в виде дерева, где корень - весь проект, ветви - модули, листья - фитчи/скрипты/стили для конкретной ветки, составте план в какой последовательности будете исправлять (от листьев - к корню, распоралеливание процесса можно делать по веткам).
Основная проблема - взаимосвязи одних модулей от других.
Если будете исправлять кодстайл - делайте это отдельными комитами и в первую очередь иначе запаретесь выискивать изменения в VCS.

**Во втором случае** - проще. Просто заново делаете проект, но следите за зависимостями.

Выберите систему контроля версий, систему тестирования, регламентируйте процесс рефакторинга заранее.

Comment: Спасибо, учту. Над деревом подумаю как реализовать, будут вопросы, отпишусь )

Система контроля версий имеется - svn.